# How to Access URL in XML Data

Tags: xml, url, processing, zillow

So I'm working on a project for class using Processing to access the Zillow API call listed here http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetUpdatedPropertyDetails.htm

Here is a sample of what the API code returns:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    - <UpdatedPropertyDetails:updatedPropertyDetails xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/UpdatedPropertyDetails.xsd /vstatic/e6e5f302965f32ad16114f7a97ba3d89/static/xsd/UpdatedPropertyDetails.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:UpdatedPropertyDetails="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/UpdatedPropertyDetails.xsd">
    - <request>
    <zpid>48749425</zpid>
    </request>
    - <message>
    <text>Request successfully processed</text>
    <code>0</code>
    </message>
    - <response>
    <zpid>48749425</zpid>
    - <pageViewCount>
    <currentMonth>172</currentMonth>
    <total>4149</total>
    </pageViewCount>
    - <address>
    <street>2114 Bigelow Ave N</street>
    <zipcode>98109</zipcode>
    <city>Seattle</city>
    <state>WA</state>
    <latitude>47.637924</latitude>
    <longitude>-122.347929</longitude>
    </address>
    - <posting>
    <status>Active</status>
    <agentName>John Blacksmith</agentName>
    <agentProfileUrl>/profile/John.Blacksmith</agentProfileUrl>
    <brokerage>Lake and Company Real Estate</brokerage>
    <type>For sale by agent</type>
    <lastUpdatedDate>2008-06-05 10:28:00.0</lastUpdatedDate>
    <externalUrl>http://mls.lakere.com/srch_mls/detail.php?mode=ag&LN=28097669&t=listings&l=</externalUrl>
    <mls>28097669</mls>
    </posting>
    <price currency="USD">1290000</price>
    - <links>
    **<homeDetails>http://www.zillow.com/HomeDetails.htm?zprop=48749425</homeDetails>**
    <photoGallery>http://www.zillow.com/Gallery.htm?zpid=48749425</photoGallery>
    <homeInfo>http://www.zillow.com/HomeInfo.htm?zprop=48749425</homeInfo>
    </links>
    - <images>
    <count>17</count>
    - <image>
    <url>http://images3.zillow.com/is/image/i0/i0/i64/ISz23uixze1pr7.jpg?op_sharpen=1&qlt=90&size=400,400</url>
    <url>http://images1.zillow.com/is/image/i0/i0/i64/ISz23uj5vihxnn.jpg?op_sharpen=1&qlt=90&size=400,400</url>
    <url>http://images1.zillow.com/is/image/i0/i0/i64/ISz0l5yjj5pajn.jpg?op_sharpen=1&qlt=90&size=400,400</url>
    <url>http://images2.zillow.com/is/image/i0/i0/i64/ISz23ukda6z543.jpg?op_sharpen=1&qlt=90&size=400,400</url>
    <url>http://images1.zillow.com/is/image/i0/i0/i64/ISz0l5xk0loazn.jpg?op_sharpen=1&qlt=90&size=400,400</url>
    </image>
    </images>
    - <editedFacts>
    <useCode>Single family</useCode>
    <bedrooms>4</bedrooms>
    <bathrooms>3.0</bathrooms>
    <finishedSqFt>3470</finishedSqFt>
    <lotSizeSqFt>4680</lotSizeSqFt>
    <yearBuilt>1924</yearBuilt>
    <yearUpdated>2003</yearUpdated>
    <numFloors>2</numFloors>
    <basement>Finished</basement>
    <roof>Composition</roof>
    <view>Water, City, Mountain</view>
    <parkingType>Off-street</parkingType>
    <heatingSources>Gas</heatingSources>
    <heatingSystem>Forced air</heatingSystem>
    <appliances>Dishwasher, Dryer, Freezer, Garbage disposal, Microwave, Range / Oven, Refrigerator, Washer</appliances>
    <floorCovering>Hardwood, Carpet, Tile</floorCovering>
    <rooms>Laundry room, Walk-in closet, Master bath, Office, Dining room, Family room, Breakfast nook</rooms>
    </editedFacts>
    <homeDescription>Bright, spacious, 4 bedroom/3 bath Craftsman, with stunning, expansive views, on one of Queen Anne's finest streets. Views of Lk Union, Lk Washington,the Cascades from Mt. Baker to Mt. Rainier, and the city-from two levels and 2 view decks. Craftsman charm intact: hardwood floors, cove moldings, crystal doorknobs, Batchelder tile fireplace. Huge gourmet eat-in kitchen with slab granite countertops, deluxe master suite, theater-like media room, level rear yard with garden space and covered patio.</homeDescription>
    <neighborhood>Queen Anne</neighborhood>
    <schoolDistrict>Seattle</schoolDistrict>
    <elementarySchool>John Hay</elementarySchool>
    <middleSchool>McClure</middleSchool>
    </response>
    </UpdatedPropertyDetails:updatedPropertyDetails>
```

I'm trying to get the raw text of the home details but the api call returns it in the `</links><links>` as a url:

```
<homeDetails>http://www.zillow.com/HomeDetails.htm?zprop=48749425</homeDetails>
```

Here is a sample of some of the text contained in there:

> You must see this one. Owner is in the business and it is
>   loaded.Brokered And Advertised By: STAGES Realty Associates of
>   SavannahListing Agent: Dennis Hall WHAT I LOVE ABOUT THE HOME
>
> Perfect community, neighborhood, and home for your large or growing
>   family. 4 bedrooms, 3 bath, 2600 sq ft. Neighborhood has walking
>   access to shopping, dining, fitness and healthcare. Neighborhood
>   boasts of pool, playground, tennis courts and manicured baseball
>   field. Perfectly located between Savannah and Hinesville. You're going
>   to love all the community this home has to offer.

Is there anyway to get the raw text out into a txt file? Zillow doesnt allow for scraping (allegedly). I could does this manually I suppose as I only have about 300 listings to parse but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible. I am also completely new to using XML so that doesnt help.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @NASA Intern I noticed you added the [Processing tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info). Are you planning to use Processing to parse the XML or a different language ?